# Unexpected character and syntax error on wp-includes/formatting.php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am getting an error on my WordPress website after changing the server. it's working on cPanel but not working on the AWS server.

I haven't change anything in this file.

[image]

This is just one screenshot. SO not allowing me to upload the code. Getting some error while uploding.
[image]

Comment: Please post line 5,948 of that file as it is on the server with the problem

Comment: @ChrisHaas, That code is too big. SO not allowing me to upload the code

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I just shared the one screen shot

Comment: @user9437856 Don't post the whole file. Find line 5948 and post the section ±10 lines.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular, Sorry for not understand your last comment. I have uploaded the image with line number 5948

Comment: This is completely  emoji arrays code.

Comment: Do you have the mbstring PHP extension installed?

Comment: I haven’t installed anything

Comment: Can you try enabling the mbstring extension for PHP

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how I got this gray code on the formatting.php page. I found this code in more than 3 places.

I download the latest version of WordPress again and updated the formatting.php and It's starting working again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I've got the same error and overwriting formatting.php has done the trick.

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**

If you use FileZilla like I do - that's where the problem comes from.

If you download your site contents with FileZilla, then the file contents get corrupted.

When you upload again, the 'unexpected characters' break Wordpress.

**Behaviour**

That explains why in my case, my DEV site was working fine.

But when I download/upload migrated the contents to a fresh QA instance then QA failed with the:

> There has been a critical error on this website.

**Solution**

I used **Nautilus** to connect to my host as a Remote Server.

When I copied my formatting.php down through Nautilus, the file opened all clean.

The FileZilla FTP copy was dinged in 3 places.

**WinSCP** is also apparently fine with this.

*Disclaimer: Not my own work*

All thanks due to this comment:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/parse-error-on-line-5925-in-formatting-php/

Comment: That is correct. I also have the same (bad) experience. Thanks for posting this.